# Find and download image on multiple pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

If I write http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/3

I can get proper image file.

However, if I set range to crawl image within multiple web page with using for loop
I can't get image file it seems 0bytes file is downloaded

f'http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/+{x}

why I can get 0bytes image file and could anyone explain how to parse image of multiple page.

Thank you

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for x in range (3,6):

    response = requests.get(f'http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/+{x}')

    print (response)


    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

    urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]


    for url in urls:
        filename = re.search(r'/([\w_-]+[400]+[.](jpg))$', url)
        if not filename:
            print("fail".format(url))
            continue
        with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
            if 'http' not in url:
                url = '{}{}'.format(response, url)
            response = requests.get(url)
            f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
modified the regex pattern and used changed the call to proper image url.
now this code will save all the images containing _400.jpg in their link as following name.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import shutil

for x in range (3,6):

    response = requests.get(f'http://www.chictopia.com/photo/show/+{x}')
    # print (response.status_code)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') 

    img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

    urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

    
    for url in urls:
        filename = re.findall(r'(.+_400\.jpg)', url)
        if len(filename) != 0:
          image =  filename[0]
          image_name = f"image_{image.split('/')[-1]}"
          response = requests.get(image, stream=True)
          with open(image_name, 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
            print(f'Saved : {image_name}')
```

for example.
http://images2.chictopia.com/photos/mikajones/2162299642/2162299642_400.jpg -> as image_2162299642_400.jpg

now whats wrong with your code:

you used wrong regex and took the matching value which is not the complete url of the image that's why you are getting the null value for image size (you are not even calling the image url).

all fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much!!